# how to Add tablespace to user in Oracle

Tags: oracle

1. Is there a way to add tablespace to a user in Oracle ?

   This means the user have more than two tablespaces;
   Why I asked this is I want to install product in each tablespace with only one users.
2. What is minimum privileges to create table, index to install Product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Tablespaces are not owned by users, but you can grant quota on a tablespace to a user with the QUOTA ON TABLESPACE command, e.g. `ALTER USER username QUOTA UNLIMITED ON tablespacename;`
2. To create a table or index, privileges required are `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,. for the first question what I wonder is if one user can own several tablespaces as MS-SQL does ?

Comment: A user doesn't own tablespace @이상봉. A tablespace is a physical partition on the disk and unrelated to a schema, which is a logical partition in the database.